# Multiple quantifier translation

Tags: logic, philosophy, quantifiers

Having some difficulty translating into English from Symbolic logic (the mixture of the quantifiers are confusing to me):

∀x(¬∃yBackOf(y, x) → Large(x))

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @yunone, I modified my question.  I agree it didn't make sense.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, I would say that as "for any $x$, if there is no $y$ such that $y$ is the back of $x$, then $x$ is large."

Comment: what do you think of "For all things that not one thing is in back of it, that thing is large."

Comment: @Kerx, yes, I believe that works as well.